# What are the risks of disabling THP?

Tags: centos, memory

When Transparent Huge Pages is disabled on CentOS 7.x is there any negative effects on the system once disabled? OOM killing? Resource spikes? There's a lot of documentation on how to disable THP in CentOS 7.x but not a whole lot of information of associated risk at the time of disabling.

I've tested turning THP off within a test environment where there isn't much load and haven't noticed any negatives so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer can be found here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/46111

"Disabling will stop only creation and usage of the new THP. The THP which were created and used at the moment the above commands were run would not be disassembled into the regular memory pages. To get rid of THP completely the system should be rebooted with THP disabled at boot time."

It only affects new THP from being created if disabled.